# simulating a stationary markov chain approach

Tags: markov-process, stationarity

I have hard time simulating a markov chain stated here:

Consider a set of N transformations `T= {t1,...,tn}` . Let `S={s1,...,sL}` be a sequence of transformations `s` of length `L`, where each element `s(i)` is chosen
from the transformations in `T`. These are binary transformations.

[image]

Given my problem I have `S={s(1),...,S(7)}` and my `max length is 7`. I am interested in calculating the Matrix P (7*7 defined here). What I understood brings me to a `P(7,1)` dimention and not `7*7`. Can anyone explain me how to build this?

As an example, here is my filtered data:

```
markovSet =

       0     1     0     0     1     1     0
       1     1     0     1     1     1     0
       1     1     0     0     0     1     1
       1     1     1     1     1     1     0
       0     0     1     1     1     1     0
       1     0     0     0     1     1     0
       1     0     0     1     0     1     0
       0     0     1     0     0     1     1
       1     0     1     1     0     0     1
       0     0     1     0     0     1     0
       1     0     0     1     0     0     1
       0     0     0     1     0     0     1
       0     1     1     0     0     1     0
       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
       0     1     1     0     0     1     1
       0     1     0     1     1     0     1
       1     1     0     1     1     1     1
       0     1     1     0     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     1     0     0
       0     1     0     0     0     1     0
       0     1     1     0     1     0     0
       1     0     0     0     0     1     1
       1     0     1     1     0     1     1
       1     0     0     1     0     0     0
       1     1     0     0     1     1     1
```

by counting/normalizing, I can generate P(s1)s as:

```
P(s1)=sum(markovSet)/norm(sum(markovSet),1)

ans =

    0.1444    0.1444    0.1222    0.1444    0.1222    0.1889    0.1333
```

the summation of them is equal to 1. I am having issue how to calculate the transition matrix to generate 7*7 matrix. Thank you.